# Multiple isset's on PHP

Tags: php, json, get, isset

How do I get an ISSET-search for example by adding id and weight, or by adding only id using JSON?

For example example.php?tag=id=3343&weight=alot

```
<?php 

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$tags= array();

$data = (object) [];
$data->id= "3343";
$data->weight= "alot";
$data->year= 42;
array_push( $data);

if( isset( $_GET['tag'])){
    echo json_encode($tags);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to iterate through all keys of URL parameters by checking them?

Comment: If it's possible to list for example all items which are over 42 years old, and weights alot, or by giving only one paramet, if this makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

function of isset can take multiple parameters, you can change like that:

```
if( isset( $_GET['tag'],$_GET['weight'], ... ))
{
echo json_encode($tags);
}
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: What would be the url then? tag=something&weight=something ? Thank you.

Comment: After the your domain should be "?" and use between variables "&".  Like this :

www.yoursite.com?myparam1=123&myparam2=abc

Comment: your url should be example.php?id=213&tag=3343&weight=alot